# Confused about a function $f : D \subset \ell^2 \to \ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f : D \subset \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ such that $$f(a) = \bigg(\sum_k \frac{2^{-k}}{1+3^{-k}-a_k},0,0,0,...\bigg) $$

and $D$ is appropriate domain so that $f$ is well-defined, i.e $D := \{a \in\ell^2 : f(a) \in\ell^2 \}$ Show that the closed unit ball is a subset of $D$ and that $f(\bar{B} _1(0))$ is unbounded in $\ell^2$

I am confused by this problem. Since $\ell^2 \subset c_0 $, the series above should converge to $0$ and so the image of $f$ is just the zero sequence. At least it should be in $c_{00}$ so it's not closed in $l^{\infty}$ but how could it be unbounded? It's also seems clear to me that $D$ could be all of $\ell^2$.

What am I missing?

Comment: $D$ cannot be $\ell ^2$ because then you will had some $a_k=1+3^{-k}$ and so the function will not be defined. By the other hand is clear that $\overline{\Bbb B }\subset D$. However I dont see the unbondedness of $f(\overline{\Bbb B })$. Probably the unboundedness is due to the factor $3^{-k}$ in the definiton of $f$

Comment: Yes, excluding $a_k = 1 + 3^{-k}$, but what about $3^{-k}$ that could caused the image to be unbounded? Shouldn't the series in any case converge to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the unboundedness part note that
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\frac{2^{-k}}{1+3^{-k}-a_k}=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\left(\frac32\right)^k \frac1{3^k(1-a_k)+1}\\
\therefore \quad \|f(a)\|=\left|\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\left(\frac32\right)^k \frac1{3^k(1-a_k)+1}\right|
$$
Now note that the sequences $e^{(k)}\in \ell ^2$ defined by the coordinates $e^{(k)}_j=\delta _{j,k}$, where the RHS is the Kronecker delta function, belong to the closed unit ball $\overline{\Bbb B }$
and you can see from above that $\|f(e^{(k)})\|\geqslant (3/2)^k$, so $f(\overline{\Bbb B })$ is clearly unbounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) cleared my misunderstanding!